# What does "moving past binary" mean in an LGBT context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have a language problem. What does "moving past binary" or "moving past binary conversation" exactly means in LGBT context?

So how it would sound in one sentence? That it's about gender binaries from the past? Sorry, but I don't know what means here to move past, like back to the past?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Would you add some context to your question. BTW, as a learner, I think binary-conversation refers to a conversation which includes only two topics.

Comment: Do you have an example of where you've seen these expressions? Off the top of my head, I believe they are referring to not thinking about gender as only male or only female, but I can't say for certain.

Comment: "Binary" (mostly likely) refers to [gender binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_binary) in this case. The "moving past" part is not as clear. You need to provide _more context_.

Comment: Furthermore, there are two kinds of people: those who can extrapolate from incomplete data, and...

Comment: Folks, I'm not sure what these old, tired jokes add to the discussion about this question. If you're making a point, it would be better if you were more explicit. @P.E.Dant (and j4eo but I can only tag one person)

Comment: @ColleenV My comment was germane, but expanding it to make its salience clear would have distracted from the question, so I have deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

That there are more sophisticated ways to think about this topic than simply two possible options (binary options) Male or Female. Moving past implies that we have travelled to a new position where we can see (understand) additional complexities.

Comment: I'm just pinging you to let you know that the question has been expanded in case you would like to expand your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As anybody who has ever filled in a form knows, in the **gender** section of the form there are two boxes: **Male** and **Female**. [Binary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/binary) in this context means that there are two (and only two) options. This works for the majority of people, but for a small minority it is a problem.

If there is a physical obstacle in our way, we need to move past the obstacle to continue on our way. If there is a mental obstacle to our understanding of a situation, for example we use only two categories for gender and this small minority does not fit either category, we need to move past the obstacle presented by this two-category approach in order to be able to think about it and talk sensibly about it.

To **move past [gender] binary**, we need (as a minimum) to add another box to the form, one that says **Other**... not just on forms, but in our minds. Here is [more information about this subject](http://nonbinary.org/wiki/Intergender).

To sum up in one sentence, as you requested:

> Classifying people as either male or female is an obstacle to understanding the small minority of people who do not fit neatly into one category or the other: we must move past this obstacle in order to reach this understanding.

Comment: I'm just pinging you to let you know that the question has been expanded in case you would like to expand your answer.